# Determining Bid type from bid history

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My head is fuzzy and I am having trouble trying to figure out how to implement the logic to determine what type of bid is being placed from a BID history.

I am trying to flag a bid as 3 or 4 different types:

1. Bid - Initial manual bid by a unique ID
2. Rebid - a subsequent manual bid by a unique ID
3. Auto - an augmented bid placed by the system that is below a unique ID's maximum bid
4. Max - The maximum bid entered for each manual entry series (bid and rebids)

Here is the data I am working with. ID through Bid are copy paste from web site.  The type column is a manual classification by me. I can't figure out how to put my logic into formulas at this time.

```
ID  Date        Time        Bid     Type
Jt  2024/02/29  16:18:39    2051.00 Rebid
Px  2024/02/29  16:18:38    2026.00 max
Px  2024/02/28  16:48:14    1825.00 auto
Gd  2024/02/28  16:48:13    1800.00 Rebid
Px  2024/02/28  16:47:40    1705.55 auto
Gd  2024/02/28  16:47:39    1680.55 Bid
Px  2024/02/28  12:34:39    1605.55 Bid
Ab  2024/02/28  12:03:55    1580.55 auto
Jt  2024/02/28  12:03:53    1555.55 max
Ab  2024/02/28  12:03:52    1550.00 auto
Jt  2024/02/28  12:03:49    1525.00 auto
Ab  2024/02/28  12:03:48    1500.00 auto
Jt  2024/02/28  12:03:41    1475.00 auto
Ab  2024/02/28  12:03:40    1450.00 Rebid
Jt  2024/02/28  10:52:41    1400.00 Bid
Ab  2024/02/28  10:52:41    1375.00 max
Ab  2024/02/27  10:41:14    1350.00 auto
Pb  2024/02/27  10:41:08    1325.00 auto
Ab  2024/02/27  10:41:07    1300.00 Rebid
Pb  2024/02/26  22:46:45    1275.00 Bid
Td  2024/02/26  22:30:49    1250.00 Bid
Fr  2024/02/26  20:21:32    1225.00 auto
Ab  2024/02/26  20:21:32    1200.00 max
Ab  2024/02/26  20:21:21    1150.00 auto
Fr  2024/02/26  20:21:20    1125.00 Rebid
Ab  2024/02/26  20:15:26    1075.00 Rebid
Fr  2024/02/26  20:15:26    1050.00 max
Fr  2024/02/26  16:56:41    1025.00 Bid
Ab  2024/02/26  13:23:11    1000.00 Bid
```

I used the remove duplicate function from the ribbon to get a list of unique IDs.  I then used the countif to get the number of entries for each ID.  Value in the Bids column

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,G2)
```

The rebids column is completely manual entry at the moment.  I was either hoping to figure out some logic to put in a formula here to do the count, or do a `COUNTIF` on the Type column.

For Max Bid I used the following formula copied down

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$D$2:$D$30/($A$2:$A$30=G2),1)
```

This is my summary table

```
Unique ID   Bids    Rebids  Max Bid
Jt          5       1       2051.00
Px          4       0       2026.00
Gd          2       1       1800.00
Ab          11      3       1580.55
Pb          2       1       1325.00
Td          1       0       1250.00
Fr          4       1       1225.00
```

This is an image of my current layout:

[image]

So for the logic so far I have this figured

- The first time a unique ID appears its a bid
- The if a name appears within say 10-15 seconds its an auto bid
- Having trouble with the max bid other than its the last bid in a series (either bid or rebid series), but I don't know how to identify that with a formula
- A bid occurs after the the auto bid time frame has expired and is not the first bid for the ID.

Technically speaking a max bid should probably be a separate category/column as an ID that only bids once is both a Bid and a Max at the same time.  Also an auto bid and a Max can also be at the same time.  This is why I said earlier 3-4 types of bids as I was not sure what to do with the max.

**If someone could help me out with a formula for either the Type column or for the rebid column or both that would be much appreciated.**

I am using Excel 2013.  As a result some of those nice new 365 feature will not work.

Comment: Not sure if I understand properly. You need a formula to clasify each bid but you are not pretty sure about the criteria for each bid type and that's the point of the question? By the way. your bid value increases 25 per row from bottom to top almost all days. I don't know why but just in case you did not notice.

Comment: The auction site puts a minimum bid increase for subsequent bids based on the value of the current maximum bid.  Ie the minimum bid increase for a 5 dollar item is not the same for a 10K item and not the same for a 130K item.  I did not look into the details on how minimum bid increase works.  It also appears that an individual's maximum bid can through the automatic increase out of whack. Hence why we see things like $0.55 for some bid endings.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I am not sure on how to identify the criteria.  I have my best guess at what is is.  Maybe someone out there sees a difference in the patter or a different criteria for identify things that would help.

Comment: I don't think you have enough data or info to make a formula. Just as example , your bid criteria *The first time a unique ID appears its a bid* is not accurate because id `Jt` got 2 bids. Do you have any other data you can add?

Comment: Is the Type the desired value in your table? E.g. for Fr you have a higher value than 1050.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns  You are absolutely right, Jt actually has a bid and a rebid. (final entry)   My table has the count right, but I put the wrong label in the type column

Comment: @Blackcat  I see where you are going with that .  The max bid in the summary table is the maximum a unique ID ever bid.  The max in the type column is the maximum for each bid or rebid by each unique ID.

Comment: I get another issue: Px line 4 and 6 why auto when there is no bid within 15 sec.

Comment: @Blackcat because they are close to the previous bid of another ID, not their own.  So in the bidding system when an other ID generates a bid, the system will automatically generate the next bid for a user ID that has a maximum bid that is greater than or equal to the current bid.  When bids tie, the tie is broken by the user who entered maximum bid first.